# search order for array of objects in find method

Tags: javascript

**I have next code:**

```js
var users = [
    {
        name: 'Mark',
        email: 'mark@mail.com',
        age: 28,
        address: 'England',
        val: true
},
{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'johnson@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'USA'
    },
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        email: 'tom@mail.com',
        age: 35,
        address: 'England'
    }];

let res = users.find(
      user => (user.name === 'John' || user.name === 'Tom'
      || user.val === true),
    );

console.log(res);
```

How I can make search by `'name'` as top priority, because now I am getting object with name `Mark` as result, but I need object with name `John` if it exists or `Tom` and if no names found search by `val`.

Comment: you want to get all the objects with `name` property?

Comment: no, also by 'val', but only if no names mached

Comment: You'll need multiple searches in one way or another. Simply because when judging the given element, you can't know if a better would come later.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let res = users.find(
      user => (user.name === 'John' || user.name === 'Tom'
      || (!user.name && user.val === true)),
    );
```

Comment: I need search by val if no names matched, in your case I will get undefined

Comment: So you want all users having name John or Tom and if no name found then search by val. Right? In this case, `find` won't work because it will return only 1 matched value.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `Array.find` method. It'd return only 1 value. You can use a `for...of` loop and have two arrays returned from it as below:

```
let prio1= [], prio2 = [];
for (const user of users) {
    if (user.name === 'John' || user.name === 'Tom') prio1.push(user);
    if (user.val) prio2.push(user);
}

let res = prio1.length ? prio1 : prio2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like the following:

```js
var users = [
  {
    name: "Mark",
    email: "mark@mail.com",
    age: 28,
    address: "England",
    val: true
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    email: "johnson@mail.com",
    age: 25,
    address: "USA"
  },
  {
    name: "Tom",
    email: "tom@mail.com",
    age: 35,
    address: "England"
  }
];

function findUser(names) {
  // use `Array.reduce` to loop through all names
  // and find the first name in the array of `users`
  var user = names.reduce((result, name) => {
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
    return users.find(user => user.name === name) || null;
  }, null);
  
  // if user was not found, find a user based on the value of `val`
  return user ? user : users.find(user => user.val);
}

var res1 = findUser(["John", "Tom"]);
var res2 = findUser(["Tom", "John"]);
var res3 = findUser(["Jeff"]);

console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
console.log(res3);
```

References:

- [Array.reduce - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

```
let userbyName = users.find(user => (user.name === 'xyz')); //Search by name

if(userbyName == null)
{  
  let userbyVal = users.find(user => ( user.val=== 'true')); //Search by Value
}
```

This will work for both cases  , put `true/false` as per you need

Answer (score 0):

You are close, change `.find()` to `.filter()` and it outputs you all users that match that criteria. I made a typo `Johnk` so it dont find `John` because of the wrong name and because he doesnt have `val`

```js
var users = [
    {
        name: 'Mark',
        email: 'mark@mail.com',
        age: 28,
        address: 'England',
        val: true
},
{
    name: 'Johnk',
    email: 'johnson@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'USA'
    },
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        email: 'tom@mail.com',
        age: 35,
        address: 'England'
    }];

let res = users.filter(
      user => (user.name === 'John' || user.name === 'Tom'
      || user.val === true),
    );

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this, it will return by val if no name is in the record

```js
var users = [
  {
      name: 'Mark',
      email: 'mark@mail.com',
      age: 28,
      address: 'England',
      val: true
},
{
  name: 'John',
  email: 'johnson@mail.com',
  age: 25,
  address: 'USA'
  },
  {
      name: 'Tom',
      email: 'tom@mail.com',
      age: 35,
      address: 'England'
  }];
   
  function srch(name,val){
    return users.filter(x=> x.name==name? x:(x.val==val?x:null))
  }
  console.log(srch("Mark",true))
```